# How to mock the background window to active state using VB script?

Tags: vbscript, window

How to mock the background window to active state using VB script?

There is some keycode command I need to send to some background window(I known the related VB function), but it will only work when the window is active. If the window is really active, I cant do anything in the foreground.

So is it there anyway to mock the window to active state?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, see this example

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'bring the window to front
'title must be exactly what you see in the titlebar of the window
oShell.AppActivate "title of your window" 
WScript.Sleep 500 'give the window the time to activate, time is in miliseconds
oShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}" 'you can send keystrokes to this window
Set oShell = nothing
```

if you want to minimize that window you can send keystrokes to do that, but this is language dependent so first try them manually. The following sends the keystrokes Alt (%) space and N from miNimize. Try in your window to push the Alt-Space keys to get the menu that controls this

```
oShell.SendKeys "(% )N"
```

Comment: It seems that in this way the window should be really activated to front, but what I want is to mock this, that is hide the "activated" window to background.

Comment: you mean minimize ? added that to my answer