# vbscript using wshshell.run and option 8, window still steals focus?

Tags: vbscript

the code:

```
WshShell.Run quote & "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.7.0-Q16\composite.exe" & quote & " -dissolve 65 -geometry +65+65 -gravity southeast C:\watermark.png " & quote & file & quote & " " & quote & file & quote, 8, true
```

quote is defined as Chr(34)

Each photo that gets processed pops up a new console box and it steals the focus of whatever I'm working on.  According to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156605.aspx I chose option 8.  I don't want to minimize the windows which seems to be the other options, just have them stay in the background.

Also I tried the following possibilites:

0 = works, but gives no indication that the process is going on.

4 = allows me to work in another window, like typing an email as long as it outside the area where the console boxes pop up, but the console boxes still render on top of everything.

6 and 7 = works, but just shows the minimized window in taskbar.  I will use option 7 if I have to.

What am I doing wrong?  Or is this the expected behavior?  Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is expected behavior. When you run wshShell.Run you are telling the program what the *initial state* of the window *should be*. That does not mean that the program behind the window can't decide to change the state.

For example, if you open notepad via wshShell.Run and pass an 8, it will cooperate and stay unfocused. But if you open Calc.exe, it always steals the focus regardless of the state you tell it to use (I only tried 0-9). Presumably composite.exe is one of those programs that won't take orders.

A possible (icky) work around would be to keep forcing your current window to take focus (which requires low security if done in IE for instance. [how to give a window focus with vbscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964630/how-to-mock-the-background-window-to-active-state-using-vb-script)).

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  I may look into other built-in methods for using ImageMagick.