# How to select a window from the background and make it the active window using batch programming / VB script

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

We are having twelve modules running in a server. Currently we have to monitor whether every module is working properly or not by logging in to the server and clicking on every individual module and checking the window. I am thinking of removing this manual dependency. I have made a VB script that can do the keyboard shortcut functions on the modules (e.g. If an MS word window is open, I can design the VB script to hit "Alt" and "F" buttons so that the "File" menu opens up). But the problem is that I can do it only on the active window and not the remaining 11 modules. Could anyone please suggest how I can programatically select another window/module?

Comment: Please check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964630/how-to-mock-the-background-window-to-active-state-using-vb-script

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the AppActivate Method. Here's the documentation for [AppActivate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzcddbek%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

Comment: thanks a lot. is there any return value for SendKeys command? I am trying to check whether my mudules work or not on the basis of this. If I am able to hit "Alt" + "F" on an active window, it would imply that this module is working. If not, I will have to send a mail to some people basing on this.

Comment: Nope it does not return anything - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83%28v=vs.84%29.aspx